# Using lexsort on higher dimensional arrays

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I could not for the life of me get array indexing to work properly with higher dimensional lexsort.

I have an ndarray `lines` of shape `(N, 2, 3)`. You can think of it as `N` pairs (start and end of a line) of three-dimensional coordinates. These pairs of vectors can contain duplicates, which should be removed.

```
points = np.array([[1,1,0],[-1,1,0],[-1,-1,0],[1,-1,0]])
lines = np.dstack([points, np.roll(points, shift=1, axis=0)])  # create point pairs / lines
lines = np.vstack([lines, lines[..., ::-1]])  # add duplicates w/reversed direction
lines = lines.transpose(0,2,1)  # change shape from N,3,2 to N,2,3
```

Since the pair (v1, v2) is not equal to (v2, v1), I am sorting the vectors with `lexsort` as follows

`idx = np.lexsort((lines[..., 0], lines[..., 1], lines[..., 2]))`

which gives me an array `idx` of shape `(N, 2)` indicating the order along axis 1:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

However, `lines[idx]` results in something with shape `(N, 2, 2, 3)`. I had tried all manner of newaxis padding, axis reordering etc. to get broadcasting to work, but everything results in the output having even more dimensions, not less. I also tried `lines[:, idx]`, but this gives `(N, N, 2, 3)`.

---

Based on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing
for my concrete problem I eventually figured out I need to add an additional

```
idx_n = np.arange(len(lines))[:, np.newaxis]
lines[idx_n, idx]
```

due to mixing "advanced" and "simple" indexing `lines[:, idx]` did not work as I expected.

but is this really the most succinct it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out I wanted

`np.take_along_axis(lines, idx[..., np.newaxis] , axis=1)`